# Log in with other iOS App (Similar to log in with Facebook)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, authentication, deep-linking

I have one app where users can create accounts and log in. Other apps will use this account to send in information on app usage.

As of now, users go from the normal apps to the login app via deep-linking, and they send their URL scheme to the login app, so the login app can return them afterwards using this URL scheme. A token is also sent back which is used to identify the user.

To get this to work the normal apps need an URL scheme in their Info.plist however. Logging in with Facebook or Twitter, this is not necessary.

Is there any way to do this without needing the URL Schemes in the Info.plist?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably build a system to accomplish this using Branch deep linking with [appended query param links](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links-other-ways/guide/#appending-query-parameters) and our [`match_guaranteed`](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/matching-accuracy/guide/#handling-personally-identifiable-information) link parameter. That would let you pass data around without needing to hard-code the URL scheme into your client apps, because all of that configuration is handled server-side. It also covers you in the situation that one of the apps isn't installed.

I imagine it would look something like this:

1. Set up the 'master' app with a Branch key
2. Set up each client app with its own Branch key
3. Build an appended params link from the client app into the master app, including some sort of identifying token(s) for the client app. This token could even be the exact return link needed, which you can generate in advance
4. Do whatever you need in the master app with the sign in or registration
5. If successful, send the user back to the client app either by building an appended params link, or using the pre-generated link if you passed that over initially

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Branch seems like a better option that what I am currently using, but I would still need to add the URI scheme for deep linking to the client apps. I would prefer if I didn't need to change the pList of each of these client apps, but I don't think there is any other way for iOS to know which apps to open, right?

Comment: Universal Links would be the only other option, but they don't work everywhere. You'd still need to make updates to the app, but just not to the info.plist file. Branch uses a combination of URL schemes and Universal Links.